Clarification on Work-Energy Theorem
The professor derived the Work-Energy Theorem using the following steps:
$F=ma$
$Fd=mad$
$W=m(v^2−u^2)/2$
$W=\frac{1}{2}mv^2−\frac{1}{2}mu^2$
$W=ΔKE$
So, it seems that work only changes the kinetic energy and has nothing to do with the potential energy of the system.
Assume I have a system consisting of the Earth and a football. Because the Earth is a part of the system, the gravitational force it exerts is an internal force and will not be involved in calculating work. An external force $$ is applied to the football, causing it to move. According to the Work-Energy Theorem, we would write that the work done by the force $$ is wholly converted into increasing kinetic energy.
If that is the case, then how do we account for the increasing gravitational potential energy? Just like the kinetic energy of the Earth-football system, gravitational potential energy is also an energy of the system. How is the gravitational potential energy of the system increased? Who is responsible for that? Is it the work done by force $$? But how can that be? The work done by the force $$ is entirely converted into increasing the kinetic energy of the system, as given by the Work-Energy Theorem.


Got an answer from a different question :

"Work does not always have to involve changes in kinetic energy. I believe your confusion stems from a misapplication of the Work-Energy Theorem. Work is only equal to change in kinetic energy if no potential fields are present (i.e. the Work-Energy Theorem only applies for free, rigid bodies). Gravity is one of these fields, so it is possible to do work without altering kinetic energy."

Is that true? because i don't see the derivation being affected by the presence or absence of potential fields.

In the work-energy theorem, the work term represents work done by all forces. Both conservative and nonconservative. Since potential energies are just rewritings of the work that conservative forces can do, $W_\text{cons}=-\Delta U$, then potential energies are included in this work term.
I prefer viewing the theorem as a direct consequence of the energy conservation law:
$$\sum E_1=\sum E_2 \quad\Leftrightarrow \\
U_1+K_1=U_2+K_2-W_\text{noncons}-Q\quad\Leftrightarrow\\
U_1-U_2+W_\text{noncons}+Q=K_2-K_1\quad\Leftrightarrow\\
-\Delta U+W_\text{noncons}+Q=\Delta K\quad\Leftrightarrow\\
\underbrace{W_\text{cons}+W_\text{noncons}}_W+\underbrace{Q}_0=\Delta K.$$
By only considering mechanical energies so that the heat term is zero, and by collecting all work by both conservative and nonconservative forces in one term $W$, the theorem follows.

Sir can you please elaborate on "potential energies are just rewritings of the work that conservative forces can do", I have always thought of potential energy as an energy stored in "system" capable or having "potential" of doing work.

@Peterswift Yes, that is exactly it! Potential energies are "stored" energies that have the potential of being released as work. Hence, this work that can be delivered is equal in magnitude to the stored potential energy. When a potential energy changes then that means that some work is being done by a conservative force. So you can call it potential energy or work done, either way it covers the same concept.

@Peterswift In your example with a football being kicked high up, gravity does a lot of (negative) work. It is this work that is stored as gravitational potential energy in this earth-and-football system. When the football falls back down again, this potential energy is being released (a negative change in potential energy) as the exact same amount of work once again. This work is then in turn immediately being converted into kinetic energy, which precisely is what the work-energy theorem states.

Sir, Wnon_cons = ΔU + ΔKE + Q, that clearly means that Work done by non_conservative force changes the potential energy U of the system. But, if Wnon_cons is changing the potential energy U of the system then what is Wcons doing ? I tried a lot understand but didn't get it.

@Peterswift Think of when you lift a book to a shelf. You exert a lifting force on the book upwards. Gravity also exerts a force on the book, just downwards, during this lifting. Your lifting force is a non-conservative force, while the gravitational force is a conservative force. Your lifting force does (positive) work, and gravity does the same amount of (negative) work. This work done by the conservative gravitational force becomes "stored" (because this same amount of work can be released later in again). And this is what we call gravitational potential energy.

I’ve been working on notes of this topic and would greatly appreciate any feedback you might have. I’ve tried to ensure they are accurate, but I’d value your perspective to confirm that everything is correct.
If you have a moment, could you please take a look at the PDF notes linked below? I understand you’re very busy, so please feel free to review them at your convenience.
[PDF Notes Link: https://www.flipsnack.com/E5E5A866AED/work/full-view.html]

Difference in kinetic energy of a system equals the work done by all the forces and moments, both internal and external, done on the system, namely
$$\Delta K = W^{tot} = W^i + W^e \ .$$
This can be easily proved integrating in time the theorem of kinetic energy, written in terms of power and proved here as shown in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/735204 as
$$\dot{ K }= P^{tot} = P^i + P^e \ ,$$
with the definitions
$$\Delta K = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \dot{K} dt \qquad , \qquad W =\int_{t_0}^{t_1} P dt \ .$$
If there is some conservative contribution, the work and power can be split as the sum of a conservative and a non-conservative contribution,
$$W^{tot} = W^{c} + W^{nc} = - \Delta V + W^{nc} \ ,$$
or
$$P^{tot} = P^{c} + P^{nc} = - \dot{ V} + P^{nc} \ ,$$
having introduced the potential $V$, and the theorem of kinetic energy can be recast as
$$\Delta E = W^{nc}$$
or
$$\dot{E} = P^{nc} \ ,$$
having introduced the definition of total mechanical (macroscopic) energy $E = K + V$ as the sum of the kinetic and potential energy.

In your professor's simplified derivation, there is an implicit assumption that there is a single constant external force $F$ acting on the object, so we know that the object is moving with a constant acceleration $a$. In this case there is no potential energy in the system (otherwise there would be some other force acting on the object as well as $F$) and indeed we have
$\displaystyle W = Fd = mad = \frac 1 2 m (v^2-u^2) = \Delta KE$
If instead the object is in a gravitational field and the force $F$ acts in the opposite direction to the weight $mg$ of the object (if the object is in a lift, for example) then we have
$F - mg = ma$
so
$\displaystyle W = Fd = mad+mgd = \frac 1 2 m (v^2-u^2) + mgd = \Delta KE + \Delta PE$
If the force $F$ is not constant because it changes magnitude and/or direction then the simplified derivation is again incorrect, and you need to use the integral $\int \vec F . \vec {ds}$ instead of $Fd$ - but you are not being introduced to such situations yet.

Sir, thanks a lot. In this situation the system is earth and the object being accelerated right ?

@Peterswift Yes, although for most purposes we assume the Earth is very much more massive than the object and so is effectively stationary. The $mgd$ potential energy term comes from the change in the relative configuration of the Earth and the object.

I'm adding a second answer to clarify what counts as work done.
I start with the simplest example:
We take the Earth as our reference of motion, since the Earth is very, very big.
You lift a ball and then you release the ball, to be accelerated by the Earth's gravity.
As the ball is accelerating downward the Earth's gravity is doing work upon the object. So during the descent the kinetic energy of the object is increasing. We can think of the process as interconversion of gravitational potential energy to kinetic energy.
Of course: we now expand our view, and we backtrack to when you were lifting the ball.
When you are lifting the ball:
Well, an exhaustively correct way of describing that is: when you are lifting the ball you are increasing the distance between the ball and the Earth, resulting in increasing the amount of potential gravitational energy of Earth-ball system.
(This reminds me of a joke from the time that Arnold Schwarzenegger was a huge moviestar: When Arnold does his push-ups he is actually pushing the Earth away from himself.)

The thing is: it's rather silly to think of the ball and the Earth as an "Earth-ball system". It's only when you get to the size of the Moon that it is meaningful to think in terms of the Earth-Moon system.

Using the Earth as reference of motion throughout is the more practical thing to do.
When you are lifting a ball:
You are doing work on the ball, increasing its gravitational potential energy.
The Earth is doing negative work on the ball.

The definition of negative work is as follows: when the direction of motion of an object is opposite to the direction in which a force is acting then that force is doing negative work.
Example of back and forth between positive work and negative work:
Let's day you are in a gym and you are using a machine that has a spring, and you are extending the spring and allowing the spring to contract again.
So you and the spring are tugging in opposite directions. When the tugging force you are exerting is a bit stronger than the contracting force of the spring you are doing work, the spring is being extended, elastic potential energy is being stored in the spring. Then you relax your effort just a bit, just enough to allow a controlled contraction of the spring. As you allow the spring to contract you are doing negative work on the spring, and the spring is doing work.
And of course there is the difference: when being extended the spring is storing energy, because when the direction of motion reverses that energy is released again. Our muscles don't have that ability.
The definitions of work done and 'negative work' only ask how much force there is, in which direction it acts, and over which distance the force is acting. Those definitions are independent of whether there is presence of  energy storing capability.



About when something counts as 'internal work'.
I take as example the Earth-Moon system. The Moon and the Earth are both orbiting the common center of mass of the Earth-Moon system. Actually, the Earth is so much heavier than the Moon that that common center of mass is still below the Earth's surface, but still: the distance between the Earth's center and the common-center-of-mass of the Earth-Moon system is significant.
The orbiting motion of the Earth-Moon system is not perfectly circular. So the distance between the Earth and the Moon changes over time. During the phase that the distance is decreasing the gravitational attraction between the Earth and the Moon is doing work. During the phase of increasing distance between the Earth and the Moon the gravitational attraction between the Earth and the Moon is doing negative work.
The Earth-Moon system is orbiting the Sun. As far as the orbit around the Sun is concerned: the cycle of work and negative-work over the course of  Earth-Moon-orbiting-their-common-center-of-mass makes no difference.
As far as the Sun is concerned that cycle is an internal affair of the Earth-Moon system.

It does have everything to do with the potential energy of the system.
Potential energy is defined as the negative of work done.
For a constant force the work done is the product of force and distance-over-which-that-force-has-acted:
With:
$W$ for work done
$ W = Fd $
Difference of potential from start point to end point:
$\Delta E_p = -Fd $
By the looks of it your professor used Torricelli's equation
$ 2a \Delta d = v^2 - u^2 $
In your notation you do allow for an initial velocity $u$ and a final velocity $u$, and to be consistent you should also have allowed initial position and end position, for instance $d_u$ and $d_v$. (In the notation that you used it is implicit that the initial position coordinate is zero, but if you set the initial position coordinate to zero you might just as well set the initial velocity value to zero.)

My preferred derivation of the work-energy theorem is as follows:
The starting point:
$$ F = ma \tag{1} $$
The next step is to evaluate an integral: integrate both sides with respect to the position coordinate, integrating from starting point $s_0$ to final point $s$:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \int_{s_0}^s ma \ ds \tag{2} $$
The work-energy theorem hinges on the fact that the two factors in the right hand side of (2), acceleration $a$ and position coordinate $s$, are not independent of each other; acceleration is the second derivative of position.
We proceed to develop the right hand side of (2).
In the steps starting with (5) the integrand $a$ is converted to velocity and the differential $ds$ is converted to $dv$, using the relations (3) and (4)
$$ v = \frac{ds}{dt} \ \Leftrightarrow \ ds = v \ dt  \tag{3}  $$
$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} \ \Leftrightarrow \ dv = a \ dt  \tag{4}  $$

(5) corresponds to the right hand side of (2)
$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds \tag{5}  $$
$$ \int_{t_0}^t a \ v \ dt \tag{6} $$
$$ \int_{t_0}^t v \ a \ dt  \tag{7} $$
$$ \int_{v_0}^v v \ dv  \tag{8} $$
First (3) was used to change the differential from $ds$ to $dt$, with corresponding change of limits. Next (4) was used - with change of limits - to arrive at (8).
So we have the following mathematical relation:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2  \tag{9} $$
Notice especially:
The definitions (3) and (4), in combined form, are sufficient to imply (9).
Stated differently: (9) expresses: whenever you have a quantity $s$, its first derivative, and its second derivative, an expression with the form of (9) is valid.

Also, it is quite remarkable to see that (9) is very similar to Torricelli's equation.
Torricelli's equation was derived for the case where there is a uniform acceleration. It turns out that when you generalize to arbitrary acceleration we end up with the same velocity containing expression: $ \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2 $

We use (9) to go from (2) to the work-energy theorem:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2  \tag{10} $$


Again: potential energy is defined as the negative of work done:
$ E_p = - \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds $
Of course with the caveat: this integral is well defined only if the outcome of the integral is independent of how the object moves from start point to end point.

As a consequence of the work-energy theorem we have:
$ \Delta E_p + \Delta E_k = 0 $
The change of kinetic energy will always match the change of potential energy. And that implies that the sum of potential energy and kinetic energy will always be a constant:
$ E_p + E_k = C $
What that means is that there is a direct relation between $F=ma$ and the principle of conservation of energy. They are not independent principles; if one holds good the other will hold good also.



Let me return to Torricelli's equation and (9):
I will use $s$ for position coordinate (instead of $d$ for 'distance')
$ 2a \Delta s = v^2 - v_0^2 $
$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2$
Here is how you can see the two in connection:
Evaluate at three positions: $s_0, s_1, s_2$
Let the acceleration be non-uniform
There are three velocities to enter the evaluation: $v_0, v_1, v_2$
We set up Torricelli's equation twice, from $s_0$ to $s_1$, and from $s_1$ to $s_2$:
$ 2a(s_1 - s_0) = v_1^2 - v_0^2 $
$ 2a(s_2 - s_1) = v_2^2 - v_1^2 $
Those two are for consecutive sections of the trajectory so it is valid to perform addition of the above two equations:
$ 2a(s_1 - s_0) + 2a(s_2 - s_1) = v_1^2 - v_0^2 + v_2^2 - v_1^2 $
And we see that the inbetween terms, the ones with $s_1$ and $v_1$, drop out of the equation:
$ 2a(s_2 - s_0) =  v_2^2 - v_0^2 $
The above construction generalizes:
If we have motion with a non-uniform acceleration we can subdivide the trajectory in small steps. With very small steps the acceleration is close to uniform over the length of each step. We can continue subdividing indefinitely; the inbetween steps will always all drop out of the equation. Hence:
$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2$



Torricelli's equation
My preferred derivation of Torricelli's equation:
We start with these standard kinematic relations for the case of uniform acceleration:
$$ v = v_0 + at \tag{11} $$
$$ s = s_0 + v_0t + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag{12} $$
The relation between (11) and (12) is: when you differentiate (12) with respect to time you get (11)
Take (12), move $s_0$ to the left hand side, and multiply everything with acceleration $a$:
$$ a (s - s_0) = a v_0 t + a \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag{13} $$
Rearrange to prepare for substituting the factor $at$:
$$ a (s - s_0) = v_0 (a t) + \tfrac{1}{2}(at)^2 \tag{14} $$
(11) can be rearranged to $at=v-v_0$. We substitute the factor $at$ with $v-v_0$:
$$ a (s - s_0) = v_0(v - v_0) + \tfrac{1}{2} (v - v_0)^2 \tag{15} $$
Multiply out the right hand side:
$$ a(s - s_0) = vv_0 - {v_0}^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - vv_0 + \tfrac{1}{2} {v_0}^2 \tag{16} $$
The terms containing the factor $vv_0$ drop away against each other, resulting in Torricelli's equation:
$$ a(s - s_0) = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2 \tag{17} $$
