Why kinetic energy is equal to work done?
My textbook says that work done is equal to the change in kinetic energy. But is there a proof for it?
( not the equation where you say
W= ½mv²- ½mu². There you substitute W with Kinetic energy. Ineed the reason why such a substitution is made.)
Does work done always result in gain of energy? Please do mention some common day examples of it.

This question is similar to: How to understand the work-energy theorem?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/822747/

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748400

My textbook says… It just says it without proving it? That seems unlikely to me.

A simple one-line proof for an object of constant mass acted on by a single constant force $F$ is
$W = Fs = mas = \frac 1 2 m (v^2-u^2)$
since $v^2-u^2 = 2as$
Proving the more general case (variable force and/or variable mass) is more difficult as it requires integration.

@gandalf61 I went back to the 2013 question that this question is flagged as a duplicate of, and I submitted an answer there. In that answer I give two derivations of the work-energy theorem. Section 1: the derivation that adresses the case of arbitrary acceleration profile straightaway, using integration. Section 2: the treatment there starts with derivation of the 2as = v^2-v_0^2 relation, and then it is demonstrated that it readily generalizes to arbitrary acceleration profile. How to understand the work-energy theorem
